# Doctrine2 ArrayCollection

Tags: lazy-loading, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

Ok, I have a User entity as follows

```
<?php
class User 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Url[]
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Url", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $urls;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->urls = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addUrl($url)
    {
       // This is where I have a problem
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is check if the User has already the `$url` in the `$urls` `ArrayCollection` before persisting the `$url`.

Now some of the examples I found says we should do something like

```
if (!$this->getUrls()->contains($url)) {
    // add url
}
```

but this doesn't work as this compares the element values. As the `$url` doesn't have `id` value yet, this will always fail and `$url` will be dublicated.

So I'd really appreciate if someone could explain how I can add an element to the ArrayCollection **without persisting** it **and avoiding the duplication**?

**Edit**

I have managed to achive this via

```
$p = function ($key, $element) use ($url) 
{ 
    if ($element->getUrlHash() == $url->getUrlHash()) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    } 
};
```

But doesn't this still load all urls and then performs the check? I don't think this is efficient as there might be thousands of urls per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet possible in a "domain driven" way, ie. just using objects. You should execute a query to check for the existance:

SELECT count(u.id) FROM User u WHERE ?1 IN u.urls AND u.id = ?2

With Doctrine 2.1 this will be possible using a combination of two new features:

1. Extra Lazy Collections
2. @IndexBy for collections, so you would define @OneToMany(targetEntity="Url", indexBy="location")
3. ExtraLazy Collection Support for index by using ->contains().

Points 1 and 2 are already implemented in Doctrine 2 master, but 3 is still missing.

Comment: So, do you think it's a good idea to create a `UrlService` with `addUrl($url, $user)` method where DQL will be used - until doctrine 2.1 is out? I assume using DQL in the entity is not possible/good idea.

Comment: or maybe `UrlService::checkIfExists($url, $user)` and run the DQL in this method?

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [exists](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/doctrine/common/collections/arraycollection.html#exists%28%29) method on the collection and manually compare values.

Comment: Hi Cobby,thanks for the reply.could you give me simple code example? I am not very familiar with the closures.

Comment: I have managed to achive this via 
`        $p = function ($key, $element) use ($url)
        {
            if ($element->getUrlHash() == $url->getUrlHash()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };`
But doesn't this still load all urls and then performs the checks? I don't think this is efficient as there might be thousands of urls per user.