# Where to put DQL's?

Tags: zend-framework, domain-driven-design, doctrine-orm

[Reference To This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839982/doctrine2-arraycollection)

Where one should put the DQL queries? In a service class, or in a controller or maybe in a repository class?

Found a nice article about this, which answers my question. I think it's best to put them in the service class.

[How to integrate Doctrine 2 with your Zend Framework application](http://www.cobbweb.me/2010/11/integrate-doctrine-2-zend-framework-application/)

Comment: Almost certainly not in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on what your DQLs are doing:

If you have a Query which is doing work on only **one entity type** I suggest to create your own **Repository class** for this entity. The repository class already provides you with the methods for find and findAll, so it would fit there good.
Doctrine gives you `orm:generate-repositories` as CLI tool. Ralph Schindler took this approach as you can see [in his example repository](https://github.com/ralphschindler/NOLASnowball).

If you have a Query which affects **multiply types of entities**, the **Service Layer** should be the best place to put it.

Comment: So looking at the referenced question above, you think best place is the repository then, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'd do so. My approach: For decoupling reasons my controllers always speak to a Service class. The service class works on the repository and flushes if needed. So it has two dependencies: the Entitymanager and the repository class (which it may resolve itself).