# Validating arraycollection in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, arraycollection, validates-uniqueness-of

I'm new to Symfony2 + Doctrine and I´m looking for a way to validate the uniqueness in an Arraycollection. May be it is already answered question but I can´t figure how resolve it.
I`ve a **Relevamientosserviciosprestador** class with a **Callback**:

```
namespace Prestadores\PrincipalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
/**
 * Prestadores\PrincipalBundle\Entity\Relevamientosserviciosprestador
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="relevServiciosPrestador")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Prestadores\PrincipalBundle\Repository\RelevamientosserviciosprestadorRepository")*
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"sonUnicosLosTiposDeReclamoq"})  
 */
class Relevamientosserviciosprestador
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    ....
    ....
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Atencionusuarioreclamo", mappedBy="relevamiento_id", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid 
     */
    private $reclamos;         
    ....
    ....
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personal = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->reclamos = new ArrayCollection();        
    }
    ....
    ....
     /*Acá intentaremos validar si los tipos de reclamo que se están cargando son únicos para ese relevamiento*/
    public function sonUnicosLosTiposDeReclamoq(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        foreach ($this->reclamos as $reclamo){
            /*Here, I get all entities, not only those related to a Relevamientosserviciosprestador*/
            var_dump($reclamo->gettiporeclamo()->getnombre());
        }
    }

}
```

And the **Atencionusuarioreclamo** entity:

```
namespace Prestadores\PrincipalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Prestadores\PrincipalBundle\Entity\Atencionusuarioreclamo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="atencionUsuarioReclamo")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Atencionusuarioreclamo
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Atencionusuariosede
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Atencionusuariosede")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nroSede", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $nrosede;

    /**
     * @var relevamiento_id
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Relevamientosserviciosprestador")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="relevamiento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $relevamiento_id;

    /**
     * @var Prmreclamotipo
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Prmreclamotipo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipoReclamo", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Assert\NotBlank()     
     */
    private $tiporeclamo;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....


}
```

I want to chek uniqueness of **tiporeclamo** in a given **sede** and **relevamiento_id**

I create or edit a **Relevamientosserviciosprestador** using a Form which has a sub form collection for **"Atencionusuarioreclamo"** entities. On submit, the callback for **Relevamientosserviciosprestador** executes but **$this->reclamos** has **all saved entities** not only those related to the **Relevamientosserviciosprestador**  what I´m editing. 
Is this the expected behauvoir or I`m missing something?
I´ve also tested the approach mentioned in [How to validate unique entities in an entity collection in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782056/how-to-validate-unique-entities-in-an-entity-collection-in-symfony2) 
but, again, it checks all entities.

I´ve also read [Doctrine2 ArrayCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839982/doctrine2-arraycollection) but I cant´t understand if it resolve the problem.
Please, can you tell me how do you manage uniqueness in your ArrayCollection before persist it? 
I´m sorry for my poor english 
Thanks in advance 
Ivan

Answer (score 2):

php's `array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )`

combined with `ArrayCollection->toArray()` and `ArrayCollection->__construct()`

In your case:

```
$Atencionusuarioreclamo = 
    new ArrayCollection(array_unique($Atencionusuarioreclamo->toArray());
```